# Onload set divs opacity to 50%

Tags: mootools, mouseover, opacity, fade, onload

Okay, so I have a site running Joomla and it is using the mootools 1.11 framework. I've fudged together a working version of this using examples from the mootools 1.2 framework but cannot get the two to co-exist even with the compatibility layer, without breaking other modules in the Joomla site.

**Question**
I have a couple of divs with a class of ".box_panel" and I have it so that they on mouseover they go from 50% opacity and back to 100% opacity on mouseleave. The problem I'm having is what is the code to set them to 50% onload?

In mootools 1.2 I used:

```
<body onload="$$('div.box_panel').fade(0.5);">
```

The code I'm using for the mouseover/mouseleave effects is:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() { 
    //first, apply a class to each of your menu element
    //$$('.links') puts every element wearing the .links class into an array
    //$$('.links').each is to browse the array an apply a function to... each of them
    $$('.box_panel').each(function(el, i) {
        //there comes exactly your former fx statement except for
        var ExampleFx = new Fx.Style(el, 'opacity', { //the fact i apply the effect on el
            wait: false, //and wait: false which make the effect not waiting (very useful on the mouseout or mouseleave function...
            opacity: 0.5,
            duration: 500,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut
        });
        //and there i apply (always on el) the effect on mouseenter (similar in this case but often better than mouseover)
        //and mouseleave (same for mouseenter but concerning mouesout)
        el.addEvent('mouseleave', function() { ExampleFx.start(1, 0.5); });
        el.addEvent('mouseenter', function() { ExampleFx.start(0.5, 1); });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just add `ExampleFx.start(1, 0.5);` before the last brackets (after the `$$('.box_panel')...` statement)?

Comment: I tried after the statement like below without success:

$$('.box_panel').each(function(el, i) {
ExampleFx.start(1, 0.5); 

Thinking about it I could just use CSS properties to set the starting opacity of the .box_panel.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Simple:</strike>

```
$$('.box_panel').effect('opacity', 0.5);
// run this right after your window.addEvent('domready', function() {
```

**Edit**: I were a bit wrong here. Mladen Mihajlovic answered completly correct. Also, here are some links for you:

- [MooTools 1.11 Documentation](http://docs111.mootools.net/)
- [MooTools 1.11 Demos](http://demos111.mootools.net/)